# Android emulator shows corrupted pink and green screen

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

My Android emulator for a Pixel 2 running Android Oreo (v26) suddenly started showing a pink and green pixelated screen every time it starts up. I am unable to recover it and it has not managed to boot successfully since.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and Android Studio 3.0.1, running NVIDIA display driver 384.90.

So far I have tried forcefully killing the emulator to prevent booting from a saved state, rebooting my workstation, and switching to the X.Org video driver. None of these have had any effect, and using the X.Org driver causes the emulator to fail to launch with a plethora of errors.

Has anybody encountered this before?

[image: Corrupted Android emulator screen]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recover the emulator by forcing a clean boot. In the AVD menu, I clicked edit settings next to my emulator, and changed the rendering mode to Software-based. This made the emulator perform a clean boot, and fixed the issue. There is also an action to perform a clean boot in the additional actions menu.

After this, I switched back to Automatic rendering mode to make use of hardware acceleration again.